# Generate different object with same attributes

Tags: java, random, deep-copy

I am building a project. One of the requirements is to generate the object with the same attributes but randomly different values. I tried to use deep-copy, but not sure if it is conceptually correct.

1. So, for example, I have a `Person` class, inherited from the abstract class `Character`.
2. And there is a `ScenarioGenerator`, which I'll put the `getRandomPerson` method to create the instances of the `Person` class.

Any help of advice is highly appreciated.

Here is part of my `Person` class:

```
public class Person extends Character {
private Random random;

private boolean pregnant;
private boolean isYou;

Person(int age, Profession profession ,Gender gender, BodyType bodyType, boolean isPregnant) {
    super(age, gender, bodyType);//pass the attributes to the super class called Character
}

Person (Person otherPerson) { //copy constructor

    this.age = otherPerson.getAge();
    this.gender = otherPerson.getGender();
    this.bodyType = otherPerson.getBodyType();
}
public Profession getProfession () { // One of the getters which generate random enum value
    //only adults have profession
    if (getAge()<=16 || getAge()>68) {
        return Profession.NONE;
    } else {
        return Profession.values()[new Random().nextInt(Profession.values().length)];
    }
}
// setters and getters
}
```

And the method of my `ScernarioGenerator` class:

```
public class ScenarioGenerator {
    public Person getRandomPerson() {
    //need age, gender, bodyType, profession, pregnancy
    Person people = new Person(person.getAge(), person.getProfession(), person.getGender(), person.getBodyType(), person.isPregnant());
    Person clone = new Person(people);
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: why do you need a copy constructor ? you are creating new objects every time. getProfession can be a static method. you can return  `people` object directly. you do not need to clone the object again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You're right. Have a nice day, sir. @SivarajVelayutham

Answer (score 2):

If you want a deeply cloned object then you can get it by implementing the clone class and overriding the clone function like

```
public class Person extends Character implements Cloneable {......}
```

Then you may simply get the new deep copied object by

```
Person clone=(Person) people.clone();
```

Comment: Thank you, but the copy constructor has its advantages outweigh the `Colneable` interface. That's the reason I choose the `copy constructor`.